# What are closures in Lua?

Tags: lua, closures

Pretty confusing, I read this from **Edition 1**:

> Technically speaking, what's a value in Lua is a closure, not the function. The function itself is just a prototype for closures.

and

> Closure is a function plus all it needs to access non-local variables correctly

*All it needs?*, but what does it *need* to access non-local variables correctly? I can't really understand this at all. Are closures any different from functions ?

Comment: "*what does it need to access non-local variables correctly*" What does it matter? Whatever it is that it needs, it has. Think of it like a black box; you aren't really supposed to care what goes into it; what matters is how it *behaves*. A function can access non-local variables; that's its behavior. How it accomplishes that doesn't matter; you can pass the value of a closure around to anywhere and it will still work.

Comment: I know it's late to ask this but your explanation on the "Implementation of closures in Lua?" question seems confusing: *"Since it is within a function, it has the right to access local variables declared outside of that function. "*          What is **it**? the "b" function? "inner" variable?

Comment: so ```local inner = 'asdf'```   is an upvalue right? or  ```inner = 10```?

Comment: `inner` is just a local variable. It is the access to `inner` which is or is not done as an upvalue, not `inner` itself. Accessing a `local` variable from a function other than the scope of the function that declared it is done through upvalues.